# Error : no viable alternative at input 'for' Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, netbeans, jython

I have strange problem,

when i am using Netbeans IDE , this line :

```
total_stock = {items : 0 for items in product_stock}
```

causes syntax Error:

> Syntax Error : no viable alternative at input 'for'

But the same code runs perfectly fine in terminal and returns this

```
>> {'rom_price': 0, 'rim_price': 0, 'ram_price': 0}
```

I am using python 2.7+ at terminal 
and python plugin Version: 0.107 and Jython plugin Version: 2.12 Source: Python for netbeans 8.0

How to solve this problem??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like jython is not able to do dictionary comprehension. As a workaround use the dictionary constructor in combination with a generator.

```
total_stock = dict((item, 0) for item in product_stock)
```

Comment: It does, i was doing same in other parts of the code, not exactly like this but yeah, this peculiar case wasnt working.!
Thanks ! though cause is still unknown

Comment: Which version of jython do you use? Dictionary comprehension is only available in python 2.7+ .

Comment: My mistake, list comprehension is working. not directory comprehension

Comment: Or, if possible, upgrade to Jython 2.7.